# Wie liest man das Zeichen „§“ vor?

Tags: single-word-request, punctuation

Einfach so. Wie spricht man *„§“* aus? Bezieht es sich immer auf Gesetze?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Das Zeichen *§* wird „Paragraph“ (auch „Paragraf“) gelesen, *§§* steht für den Plural „Paragraphen“.

Lesebeispiele:

- *nach § 263 StGB*: „nach Paragraph zweihundertdreiundsechzig Es-Te-Ge-Be“ bzw. „nach Paragraph zweihundertdreiundsechzig Strafgesetzbuch“ oder „nach Paragraph zweihundertdreiundsechzig des Strafgesetzbuchs“
- *vgl. §§ 121, 124, 626 Abs. 2 BGB*: „vergleiche (die) Paragraphen hunderteinundzwanzig, hundertvierundzwanzig, sechshundertsechsundzwanzig Absatz zwei Be-Ge-Be“
- *in den §§ 511 ff. ZPO*: „in den Paragraphen fünfhundertelf (und) folgende Zett-Pe-O“

Das Paragraphenzeichen wird selten (früher häufiger) auch in anderen Bereichen benutzt, um Abschnitte zu bezeichnen, aber heute als „typisch juristisch“ wahrgenommen. Dies sogar so sehr, daß das Zeichen alleine (ohne Nummer) als Symbol für das Recht, die Justiz, das akademische Fach Jura usw. verwendet wird.

(In juristischen Texten benutzt man das Paragraphenzeichen nur zusammen mit einer Nummer, mit einem Leerzeichen dazwischen. In Wendungen wie *Der folgende Paragraph enthält ...* wäre es ein Fehler, das Wort *Paragraph* durch das Zeichen zu ersetzen.)

Im juristischen Bereich werden Paragraphen nicht nur in Gesetzen verwendet, sondern beispielsweise auch in Vertragstexten. Andererseits sind nicht alle Gesetze in Paragraphen eingeteilt, sondern manche stattdessen in *Artikel* (Abkürzung „Art.“).

Answer (score 5):

Man liest es "Paragraph" vor, und selten wird es auch außerhalb juristischer Kontexte zum Gliedern von Texten verwendet; lt. Karl v. Moor etwa von Martin Heidegger in *Sein und Zeit*.